# Select list - removing appended elements after using getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

In my form I have two items selectors. Selecting the first one should always clear the second list (all elements) and populate it with appended options that I get using getJSON. I have tried at least dozen different ways to do it (e.g. .empty(), .find and .remove) but nothing really works. Thanks in advance!

```
<form id="devuser" action="#" class="form-horizontal form-seperated" method="post">
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="col-md-3"><select id="select1" class="form-control select">
            <option value="m">M</option>
            <option value="f">F</option>
        </select></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><select id="select2" class="form-control select">
        </select></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here goes js code with .empty() example but I also tried .find('option') and .remove().

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
var userurl = urldv + $(this).val();
  $.getJSON(userurl).done(function(data){
      for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
          $("#select2").append('<option id="al'+i+'" value="'+data[i].im+'"</option>');
          $("#device"+i).append(data[i].dn;
      }
  });
  $("#select1").change(function() {
    $("#select2").empty();
        });
    });
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis on this line: `$("#device"+i).append(data[i].dn;`.

Comment: And do not append in a loop as DOM scan/manipulation is expensive!

Answer (score 1):

Using `.empty()` should work to remove all the option elements.

Issues:

(1) You are missing a closing parenthesis on the following line:

```
$("#device"+i).append(data[i].dn;
```

(2) You are registering a second change-event handler inside the first when you should be just executing the code that is in that handler:

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
    var $select1 = $(this),
        $select2 = $("#select2"),
        userurl = urldv + $select1.val();

    $select1.attr('disabled', true);
    $select2.empty();
    $.getJSON(userurl).done(function(data) {
        var optionHtml= '';
        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
            optionHtml += '<option id="al' + i + '" value="' + data[i].im + '"</option>';
            $("#device" + i).append(data[i].dn);
        }
        $select2.append(optionHtml);
    }).always(function() {
        $select1.attr('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Note:

1. The code above shows how you can prevent overlapping ajax calls by temporarily disabling the first select element.
2. As others have pointed out, it is more efficient to append all the option elements at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out. The idea is to load the JSON values to a variable then .html it into the selectbox.

```
$(function(){ 
 var JSONvalue = '';
 $.getJSON(userurl).done(function(data){
   for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
   var JSONvalue += ('<option id="al'+i+'" value="'+data[i].im+'"</option>');
   }
 });

   $("#select1").change(function() {
      $('#select2').html(JSONvalue);
   });
});
```